# Finding last occurence of string

Tags: c

I want to find the last occurrence of string in a string (which is not NULL- terminated).
The searched substring is always 4 letters long. This is what I tried:

```
char * strrstr(char *string, char *find, ssize_t len)
{
  //I see the find in string when i print it 
  printf("%s", string);
  char *cp;
  for (cp = string + len - 4; cp >= string; cp--)
  {
    if (strncmp(cp, find, 4) == 0)
        return cp;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

It gives me NULL all the time although I see the substring, which I'm looking for in string argument.

Comment: Can you give an example `main` that calls this with data that gives the wrong result?

Comment: If `string` isn't terminated (and, strictly speaking, thus is not actually a string, in C), you really can't `printf()` it like that.

Comment: @interjay found the reason. String was malloc'ated for 5k. and I have always checked only the first bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code in this way and it works successfully

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * strrstr(char *string, char *find, ssize_t len)
{
  //I see the find in string when i print it 
  //printf("%s", string);
  char *cp;
  for (cp = string + len - 4; cp >= string; cp--)
  {
    if (strncmp(cp, find, 4) == 0)
        return cp;
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
   char *ret = strrstr("kallelkallelkallelkallaa", "kall", 23);
   printf("%s", ret); //---> it prints: kallaa
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You pass `strlen("kallelkallelkallelkallaa")-1` as 3rd parameter by intention?

Comment: if the `needle` char array is at the very end of the `haystack` then the posted answer will fail to find the last occurrence of the `needle`  I.E. the third parameter to the `strrstr()` needs to be the returned value from a call to strlen()